# Laravel mix, long-term caching and async loading scripts

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-5, laravel-mix

This is where technology is annoying. 3 days ago I upgarded from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4. Despite of a bad upgrade guide offered by Laravel documentation, totally found out I have to migrate from `Gulp` to `Webpack` (which I was not familiar with).

It's 2 Days, I'm still searching about Webpack to know how I can do a job which was so simple before. There isn't any clear notes out there. Even I can't understand what is the best practices for a website with so much styles and scripts.

**Sorry for nagging so much.** I'm really confused.

---

Assume I have 15 CSS files in two parts. 5 of them are common files which are used in both user and admin panel and both panels have 5 specific files. The same structure for JS files.

Also want to use long-term cache, whilst avoid render-blocking JavaScript files (async/defer).

**With Gulp** I could easily merge all Styles and JavaScripts in 3 bundles. It was so simple to async them and also long-term caching was OK.

**With Webpack** If I use `mix.js()` long-term caching is OK but I can't  load them asynchronous because Webpack has it's own bootstrapper.

If I use `mix.scripts()` or `mix.combine()`, I'm able to load scripts asynchronous, but now `npm run watch` won't watch for changes in those javascript files.

I prefer to use what Laravel is suggesting, but that's really annoying. Where can I find a simple example of a website implemented by Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Mix?

I have seen [JeffreyWay](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix-example)'s example but that's very basic and so much far from a real website.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I decided to doing so, but `mix.version()` was not working any more. I searched about the error and found nothing. Then thought maybe it's related to node modules which should be updated or changed. Because `package.json` is different in Laravel 5.4, it was changed to Webpack automatically. I have no idea if discarding changes makes that errors again or not.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to show your `webpack.mix.js` for anyone to see in order to help you?